# Function reassignment in 'Learn You a Haskell: Starting Out'

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, semantics, definition

We create this function:

```
conanO'Brien = "It's a-me, Conan O'Brien!"
```

The author then states, "Because we can't change what names (and functions) mean once we've defined them, conanO'Brien and the string "It's a-me, Conan O'Brien!" can be used interchangeably."

Yet, I can make the reassignment `conanO'Brian = 2` with no trouble. What does he mean by "we can't change what names (and functions) mean"?

Comment: You can define a new variable of the same name _shadowing_ the previous variable and with a different value, but you can't change the variable's value.

Comment: You can't reassign in a .hs file. In GHCi, the REPL lets you redefine a binding, much as if you wrote two nested bindings `let x= ... in let x= ... in ...`, but this is no reassignment, only shadowing of the outermost `x`.

Comment: Try this in GHCi. `x = 10` and then `f y = x+y`. Then, try to "reassign" to `x`, and observe that `f` is not affected by that -- `f y` still returns `10+y`.

Comment: `"conanO'Brian" == "conanO'Brien"` ==> `False`.